# Stop crontab from filling syslog Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, cron, syslog, rsyslog

How can I prevent (certain cronjobs) from filling my syslog in Ubuntu 15.04?
I have some jobs that run 4 times a minute and quickly fill up my syslog files.

I've tried adding:

```
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
```

to /etc/rsyslog.conf, but this didn't resolve anything.

The current output is:

```
Aug  8 06:58:01 localhost CRON[25706]: (gijs) CMD (   sleep 15; unison -batch /var/www ssh://server1//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 localhost CRON[25703]: (gijs) CMD (   sleep 30; unison -batch /var/www ssh://server2//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 localhost CRON[25708]: (gijs) CMD (unison -batch /var/www ssh://server2//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 localhost CRON[25713]: (gijs) CMD (   sleep 30; unison -batch /var/www ssh://server1//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 localhost CRON[25714]: (gijs) CMD (   sleep 45; unison -batch /var/www ssh://server1//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 localhost CRON[25717]: (gijs) CMD (   unison -batch /var/www ssh:// server3//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 localhost CRON[25719]: (gijs) CMD (   sleep 15; unison -batch /var/www ssh:// server3//var/www)
Aug  8 06:58:01 localhost CRON[25690]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug  8 06:58:01 localhost CRON[25694]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug  8 06:58:08 localhost CRON[25588]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: Why did you delete your previous version of this question (711708) and then immediately ask this one?